# control a number of sms sent in android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

i make an application for sending sms automatically to the incoming Number. But the problem is that ,it send 2 sms instead of one in each call.
i verified in my log, my "onreceive()" method for broadcastReceiver is called twice at the phone state changed and i dont know how to control this.
have someone an idea? thanks for hepl
sorry for my twisted english.

Comment: Did you check the call state in the extra [EXTRA_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_STATE).

Comment: yes i did this: the first sms is sent when EXTRA_STATE is RINGING and the second when IDLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(EXTRA_STATE == RINGING)
    sendSMS();
```

Can you only check the ringing state of the incoming call?
It will ensure your sms is sent only once when the incoming call is at ringing state, not others.